# Celery tasks should be queued on worker getting lost

Tags: django, task, celery, worker

I am using django-celery 3.2 and celery 3.1.25.
I have added below settings -

```
CELERY_TASK_ACKS_LATE = True
task_reject_on_worker_lost = True
```

The application results in below error and fails to load if I use celery 4.x with django-celery 3.2

> ImportError: No module named vine.five

**Steps to reproduce**

Trigger some tasks, and get their pids from logs. I kill a worker(pid) at random using kill command.

**Expected behavior**

The task should come back to the queue and picked up by same or other worker.

**Actual behavior**

The task is getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `django-celery` with newer versions of celery.

> Previous versions of Celery required a separate library to work with Django, but since 3.1 this is no longer the case. Django is supported out of the box now so this document only contains a basic way to integrate Celery and Django.

When using celery 4.x as you mentioned, you can read here (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) about how to use celery with Django.

Comment: Is there a work around to by pass django-celery, and use celery 4.x features for a django application?

Comment: As the document says in its first two sentences. `Previous versions of Celery required a separate library to work with Django, but since 3.1 this is no longer the case. Django is supported out of the box now so this document only contains a basic way to integrate Celery and Django.` So the first step is to remove django-celery and then fix any configuration errors that might happen.